# How to run a "subshell" command in windows vscode powershell terminal

Tags: linux, command-line, powershell

I have this command:

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer @(Invoke-Command {gcloud auth application-default print-access-token})" https://speech/googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize -d @X:\Dropbox\andela-docs\phase-II-docs\google-machine-learning-apis-designing-implementing-solutions\demos\datasets\data-linear16.json
```

In linux this command would be run like this:

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" https://speech/googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize -d @X:\Dropbox\andela-docs\phase-II-docs\google-machine-learning-apis-designing-implementing-solutions\demos\datasets\data-linear16.json
```

I am trying to get the windows powershell equivalent of this portion `$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)"` of my curl command so I can pass in the token

Answer (score 0):

Point of note:

PowerShell can use curl.exe just as you can from cmd.exe.  However, using the command curl without the extension '.exe', means you are using the PowerShell alias and thus not the same thing. So, either use 'curl.exe' directly, in PowerShell with its normal command specifications, or you'd need to look deeper at ***IVR*** thus changing how you approach this.

As per the builtin PowerShell help.

```
Get-Help -Name Invoke-WebRequest | 
Format-List -Force

<#
CommonParameters         : True
WorkflowCommonParameters : False
details                  : @{name=Invoke-WebRequest; noun=WebRequest; verb=Invoke}
Syntax                   : @{syntaxItem=System.Object[]}
parameters               : @{parameter=System.Object[]}
inputTypes               : @{inputType=}
relatedLinks             : @{navigationLink=System.Management.Automation.PSObject[]}
returnValues             : @{returnValue=}

***
aliases                  : iwr
                           wget
                           curl
***

remarks                  : Get-Help cannot ...
PSSnapIn                 : 
alertSet                 : 
description              : 
examples                 : 
Synopsis                 : 
                           Invoke-WebRequest [-Uri] ...

ModuleName               : Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
nonTerminatingErrors     : 
xmlns:command            : http://schemas.microsoft.com/maml/dev/command/2004/10
xmlns:dev                : http://schemas.microsoft.com/maml/dev/2004/10
xmlns:maml               : http://schemas.microsoft.com/maml/2004/10
Name                     : Invoke-WebRequest
Category                 : Cmdlet
Component                : 
Role                     : 
Functionality            : 
#>
```

When using any external PowerShell command, quoting and special handling if required.

> - [PowerShell: Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)
> - [Solve Problems with External Command Lines in PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/solve-problems-with-external-command-lines-in-powershell)
> - [Top 5 tips for running external commands in Powershell](https://powershelleverydayfaq.blogspot.com/2012/04/top-5-tips-for-running-external.html)
> - [Execution of External Commands in PowerShell Done Right](https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/execution-of-external-commands-in-powershell-done-right)
> - [Using Windows PowerShell to run old command-line tools (and their    weirdest parameters)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2012/03/03/using-windows-powershell-to-run-old-command-line-tools-and-their-weirdest-parameters)

See also about Redirection

> - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6
> - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220933/powershell-pipe-external-command-output-to-another-external-command